# Data of MySql Docker Container doesn't persist after docker-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, microservices, persistent-volumes

I am running two docker container:

- docker-mysql-activity
- activity-service

and I make sure of the persistence of the data thanks to the volumes.

That's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  docker-mysql-activity:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: docker-mysql-activity
    volumes:
    - mysql_activity:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33061:3306
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin123
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=SCactivity
        - MYSQL_USER=testuser
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=testuser@123

  activity-service:
    image: activity-service:latest
    container_name: activity-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=activity-service
    hostname: activity-service
    build:
      context: ./activity-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    depends_on:
      - service-registry
      - docker-mysql-activity

volumes:
  mysql_activity:
```

When I execute **docke-compose up** everything goes smoothly and volumes are created, I have verified that looking in the volumes folder of Docker and It saves data correctly (all verified with postman - GET and POST data works correctly).

The problem occurs when I try **docker-compose down** or **docker-compose stop** and then **docker-compose up** again, data no longer persist.

I am sure that the issue is not related to **docker-compose down** because the volume persists, instead it is the data inside volume which are reset when I execute the command **docker-compose up**.

Comment: Does this happen if "activity-service" is not included in the compose file? Can you provide a [mcve] that doesn't depend on commands and files we don't have in the question?

Comment: @BMitch it doesn't happen if "activity-service" is not included in the compose file. It seems that the service override the database, but in the .yml file of activity service I have this:  jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql-activity:3306/SCactivity?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

**activity-service** is a Spring Boot Microservice.

It has this application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 9001

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql-activity:3306/SCactivity?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: testuser
    password: testuser@123
    hikari:
      initialization-fail-timeout: 0
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

and the table Class is Activity.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Activity")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Activity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ACT_ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private final String name;
    @Column(name = "DESCR")
    private final String descr;
    @Column(name = "fitness")
    private Boolean fitness;
    @Column(name = "nuoto")
    private Boolean nuoto;


    public Activity() {
        this.name = "";
        this.descr = "";
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**
The problem was here:

```
server:
  port: 9001

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql-activity:3306/SCactivity?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: testuser
    password: testuser@123
    hikari:
      initialization-fail-timeout: 0
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

Replace

```
ddl-auto: create
```

with

```
ddl-auto:update
```